# iterate object inside objects based on objecte selected inside dropdown using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

here is my json :

```
{
    "heavy vehicles": {
        "trucks": [
            "tata",
            "jvc"
         ]
    },
    "light vehicles": {
        "cars": [
            "alto",
            "wagonr"

        ],
        "jeeps": [
            "abc",
            "def"
         ]
    },
}
```

what i want to do is : their are 3 dropdowns one is having values to select vehicle type : options would be heavy and light vehicles , second dropdown should populate values based on selected vehicle type if heavy vehicle is selected then option would be truck , third dropdown will have the values based on second dropdown if truck is selected the options would be tata and jvc.

i m able to iterate through first level of objects in one dropdown , how wil i iterate through second level depending on the dropdown selected inside first level

all data is dynamic any level values can get changed

kindly help

my js code :

```
processList = [];

for (var key in response) {      
                        if (response.hasOwnProperty(key))
                        processList.push(key);
                        console.log("object" +  processList);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
  $scope.data = {
    "heavy vehicles": {
        "trucks": [
            "tata",
            "jvc"
         ]
    },
    "light vehicles": {
        "cars": [
            "alto",
            "wagonr"

        ],
        "jeeps": [
            "abc",
            "def"
         ]
    },
};
  
  $scope.initSelect2 = function(key){
    $scope.select2 = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.data,function(v,k){
          if(key === k)
            $scope.select2.push(v);
        });
    }
  
  $scope.initSelect3 = function(key1,key2){
      $scope.select3 = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.data,function(v,k){
          if(key1 === k)
           {
             angular.forEach(v,function(v1,k1){
                 if(key2 === k1)
                   $scope.select3.push(v1);
               })
           }
        });
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   
  <select ng-model="model1" ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in data" ng-change="initSelect2(model1)"></select>
  <select ng-model="model2" ng-options="key1 as key1 for (key1,value1) in select2[0]" ng-change="initSelect3(model1,model2)"></select>
    <select ng-model="model3" ng-options="key2 as key2 for key2 in select3[0]"></select>
  
</div>
```

Comment: what about creating dropdown with ng-repeat ? how will i do that if i have to create dropdown too dynamically?

Comment: using `ng-options` is better than `ng-repeat`. what is your mean dynamically?

Comment: i mean that my dropdown are created dynamically using ng-options and all of they are having ng-model value same , what do in that case ?